# Python, многопоточность, мониторы/семафоры, критический ресурс

Tags: python, многопоточность

Доброе время суток, дорогие пользователи StackOverflow, подкрепить вопрос кодом не получится, но и без кода достаточно легко, вопрос скорее теоретический.

Есть поток (`T1`), который в цикле записывает что-то в файл, также есть поток (`Т2`), который каждые 100 мс просыпается и читает этот файл во вред `Т1`. В этом случае должна возникнуть ошибка, т.к. файл (у `Т1` и `Т2` он общий) является критическим ресурсом, только один поток должен быть его владельцем. Собственно ошибку при выполнения кода не наблюдаю. В чём проблема?

Comment: Поясните, что значит "во вред", какую именно ошибку вы ожидаете, почему считаете, что только один поток может быть владельцем и что именно значит "быть владельцем".

Comment: Операционные системы не запрещают читать занятый файл, python тут ни при чём

Comment: @andreymal понял, спасибо!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вроде как у любого файла есть поле "Владелец", которое появляется в момент исполнения. Я думал, что у файла в какой-то момент времени может быть один владелец

Comment: @chattingtoofast блокировки можно (и нужно) применять в некоторых случаях ([такое нередко встречается в Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOfxh.png)), но по умолчанию их нет и файлы нужно блокировать самостоятельно